# Frequency time series on SAS Visual Analytics requires compress count by month

Tags: sas, sas-visual-analytics

I have two columns, one as Acutal_date and another as Incident_ID

```
Actual_date    Incident_ID
12/02/2014      W23421
02/12/2015      W234234
```

I want to create a simple time series plot in SAS VA that displays count by Month-Year. For example, Feb-2014 == count as 1, Mar-2014 == count as 0 ... I refomart the Actual_date variable into MMYYYY, but when I do the time series plot, the count doesn't compress as Month-Year, but still actual dates, so I get a lot of 1's across the board.

Comment: SAS VA questions are better posted on communities.sas.com IMO.

Comment: Yeah, I don't think VA is really programming (at least, not the use you're describing here).

Comment: Is there a session on stackoverflow that I can ask SAS VA related questions? I tried asking questions on SAS community, they are not mature and not very throughout or capable to answer my basic questions at all.